# Meaning of "fix" in the provided context

Tags: meaning-in-context

> How to fix fake news? ([Source](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/10/15/opinion/facebook-fake-news-philosophy.html))

What is the meaning of "fix" in the above?

Among all senses of "fix", it seems to me that the following is closer to meaning of the word in the above sentence.

> [mend or repair.](https://www.google.com/search?q=fix%20meaning&rlz=1C1CHZL_enIR762IR762&oq=fix%20meaning&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j69i59j69i60l3.1651j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) "you've forgotten to fix that shelf"
>   synonyms: repair, mend, patch up, put right, put to rights, set right,
>   get working, make as good as new, see to; More

But, then I don't understand how can one mend/repair fake news. Is there any better suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, there can be meanings with additional connotation.  Consider this expanded set of definitions from the Oxford Dictionaries:

> ***[fix](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fix)***
>
> **VERB**
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> 3. Mend or repair.
>
>    *‘you've forgotten to fix that shelf’*
>
>    3.1 Put (a bad or unwelcome situation) right.
>
>    *‘the international community should not rely on the UN to fix the world's problems’*
>
>    3.2 (*fix something up*) Do the necessary work to improve or adapt something.
>
>    *‘we were trying to fix up the house so that it became vaguely comfortable’*

In this case, the word ***fix*** is being used to mean definition 3.1, *Put (a bad or unwelcome situation) right.*

There is potential for some humour here, in that definition 6 is a big part of the problem with *fake news*, in that it was used to affect the outcome of the last US Presidential election:

> 6. *informal* Influence the outcome of (something, especially a race, match, or election) by illegal or underhand means.
>
>    *‘the club attempted to fix last Thursday's league match’*

Because *fake news* was used to ***fix*** the election, we have to ***fix*** the problem of *fake news*.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is "Yes", in the context you provide "fix" means to mend or repair, or as Roger suggests it may also mean to put a a bad situation right.

I think there is another piece to your question though:

As constructed, there is an implicit clause in the headline: "How to fix (the problem of) fake news." Perhaps when you see it written out that way, it helps to explain why the headline's usage is correct?